# Output with PHP the value of a variable or a pre-defined CONSTANT from a MySQL result string

Tags: php, mysql, string, variables

I have a string stored in MySQL db, like this:

```
The sky is $color and</br> the grass is GRASS_COLOR
```

When I fetch this from the db and echo I get output

```
The sky is $color and 
the grass is GRASS_COLOR
```

Although I already defined GRASS_COLOR constant (ie. define('GRASS_COLOR', 'green'); ) earlier in the script and $color variable (ie. $color='blue';).
Note, it does properly break the line using html 
Is there a way to fetch the string from the database and make it output instead, after fetching it from the db:

```
The sky is blue and 
the grass is green
```

**EDIT:** I took Danijel excellent solution and modified it a bit to make it a function, which can now be used on any fetched MySQL (or other) string

```
$color = 'blue';
define('GRASS_COLOR', 'green');
$foo = 'The sky is $color and</br> the grass is GRASS_COLOR'; // place here value from database

function db_fetch_vars_constants($text) {

// collect all defined variables and filter them to get only variables of string and numeric type
//$values = array_filter( get_defined_vars(), function( $item ) {
$values = array_filter( $GLOBALS, function( $item ) {
    return is_string($item) || is_numeric($item);
});

// append the dollar sign to keys
$keys = array_map( function( $item ) { 
    return '$'.$item;
}, array_keys( $values ) );

// create the final array by combining the arrays $keys and $values
$vars = array_combine( $keys, array_values( $values ) );

// replace names of the variables with values
$text = str_replace( array_keys( $vars ), array_values( $vars ), $text );

// collect all constants and replace user defined constants with values
$constants = get_defined_constants( true );
$text = str_replace( array_keys( $constants['user'] ), array_values( $constants['user'] ), $text );

// we are done
echo $text;
}

//call the function. show the result
db_fetch_vars_constants($foo);
```

Comment: Your problem is with the fact you are storing your variables in MySQL. Php is not evaluating them as variables, the whole line is treated as text. You need to look at your logic

Comment: As I explained to Jacek, I have both php FAQ system and information-pages system that their data is stored in the db and fetched from there. There are some details, like prices, that must be set as variables, because they need to either change according to the user session information (different user groups) or currency the user has selected, thus hard coded string is a problem. His solution/workaround is a way to do fix that, I did something like Jacek workaround: $faq['answer'] = str_replace('MIN_ORDER_STARTER', $currencies->format(MIN_ORDER_STARTER), $faq['answer']); are there better ways?

Comment: I see what you are trying to do but it seems more like the problem lies with how you are presenting your pricing. Can you get a link up? If the workarounds are ok use them but there's probably a more sensible way forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe if you save the DB strings in [sprint_f](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) format, i don't see another way:

```
$color = 'blue';
define('GRASS_COLOR', 'green');

$text = 'The sky is %s and the grass is %s';
$text = sprintf( $text, $color , GRASS_COLOR );

echo $text;
```

### UPDATE

Apparently I was a little too hasty with constatation '**i don't see another way**'. Actually this is definitely achievable with the use of [get_defined_vars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) and [get_defined_constants()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) functions. The idea is to collect all user defined variables and constants, and then to replace that in a string. This could even be a simple template engine ( if does not already exists ).

```
// place here value from database
$text = 'The sky is $color and</br> the grass is GRASS_COLOR';

$color = 'blue';
define('GRASS_COLOR', 'green');

// collect all defined variables and filter them to get only variables of string and numeric type
$values = array_filter( get_defined_vars(), function( $item ) {
    return is_string($item) || is_numeric($item);
});

// append the dollar sign to keys
$keys = array_map( function( $item ) { 
    return '$'.$item;
}, array_keys( $values ) );

// create the final array by comining the arrays $keys and $values
$vars = array_combine( $keys, array_values( $values ) );

// relpace names of the variables with values
$text = str_replace( array_keys( $vars ), array_values( $vars ), $text );

// collect all constants and replace user defined constants with values
$constants = get_defined_constants( true );
$text = str_replace( array_keys( $constants['user'] ), array_values( $constants['user'] ), $text );

// we are done
echo $text;
```

Comment: It actually should be a template engine or a built-in function in PHP if you ask me...

Comment: No problem, it turned out to be an interesting question.

Comment: Any way to make this code a function? Like "function db_fetch_vars_constants($text) {}"

Comment: I see you've found a solution how to make a function by using $GLOBALS array instead of get_defined_vars(), nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'The sky is $color and the grass is GRASS_COLOR';
$string = str_replace('$color', $color, $string);
$string = str_replace('GRASS_COLOR', GRASS_COLOR, $string);
```

But this isn't a good idea to store such a string in MySQL. I hope this is only for learning purposes.

BTW. If you've got many more variables, this is going to be a little complicated. But there is something wrong with the whole idea, so let's say that this is a 'stupid workaround'. If you will write what is the problem and why you are storing something like that in database, we can help to create a better solution.

Comment: Heh, I hope so. Because storing things in MYSQL in that form is not the best idea... Thx for comment!

Comment: @Jacek Regarding the "why", I have both php FAQ system and information-pages system that their data is stored in the db and fetched from there.
There are some details, like prices, that need to be variables, because they need to either change according to the user session information (different user groups) or currency the user has selected, thus hard coded string is a problem.
Your solution/workaround is a way to do fix that, I did something like:

     $faq['answer'] = str_replace('MIN_ORDER_STARTER', $currencies->format(MIN_ORDER_STARTER), $faq['answer']);

are there better ways?